# How to use img tag instead of canvas tag inside openseadragon NAVIGATOR?

Tags: angular, openseadragon

How to use **img** tag instead of **canvas** tag inside openseadragon **NAVIGATOR**?

with useCanvas: false main canvas tag in viewer is replaced by img tag but how to do the same in navigator (need to replace canvas with img inside navigator).

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to maintain aspect ratio of the image, so if img tag tag is there I can apply my own css to img tag to maintain aspect ratio.

In viewer by using usecanvas: false I can apply css to it but for navigator I can't convert canvas tag to img tag, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Neither the viewer nor the navigator is a single img tag even without useCanvas. If you want to make the viewer have the correct aspect ratio, you have to specify both width and height. The navigator by default uses the aspect ratio of the viewer, so if you've properly set up the viewer, the navigator should be good. There are other options for customizing the size and aspect ratio of the navigator if you need.

Comment: Can you provide solution for how to maintain aspect ratio for both viewer and navigator and also options for customizing the size and aspect ratio of the navigator.

Comment: By default the viewer and navigator share the same aspect ratio. To find all of the settings you can go to http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/OpenSeadragon.html#.Options and search for "navigator".